# How to populate select dropdown based on first select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I have read many different articles on this including https://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html and http://blog.chapagain.com.np/using-jquery-ajax-populate-selection-list/

But it is not working for me, and I do not know why.

HTML

```
div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="selectComplvl" class="regions" >Region</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <select class="form-control levelbox" id="region" value="" name="region">
                        <option value="base">---Select---</option>
                        <?php
                          $region_sql = "SELECT * FROM `regions`";
                          $region_res = mysqli_query($con, $region_sql);
                          if(mysqli_num_rows($region_res) > 0){
                             while($region_row = mysqli_fetch_array($region_res)){
                                  echo "<option value='".$region_row[id]."'>".$region_row[region]."</option>";
                              } 
                          }

                        ?>

                      </select>
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="compEntered" class="comp">compeition Entered</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <select class="form-control" id="compEntered" name="compEntered">
                        <option value="base">Please choose a Region</option>

                      </select>
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

getcomp.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sql=mysqli_query("select * from comp_entered where region_id='$id'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['region_id'].'">'.$row['comp_entered'].'</option>';
}
}
?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#region").change(function()

                                             {
                            var id=$(this).val();
                            var dataString = 'id='+ id;
                            $.ajax
                            ({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "getcomp.php",
                                data: dataString,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(html)
                                {
                                    $("#compEntered").html(html);
                                }
                            });
                        });
});
```

TABLE regions

| **id** |     **region**  |

| 1  | mid ameria    |

| 2  | mid atlantic  |

| 3  | sounthern usa |

TABLE comp_entered

| **id** | **region_id** | **comp_entered** |

| 1  | 1 | compA |

| 2  | 1 | compB |

| 3  | 2 | comp C |

| 4  | 2 | compD  |

| 5  | 3 | comp E |

| 6  | 3 | comp F |

what is wrong with my code? What is the best way to make this work?

Comment: Doing immediately an echo inside your getcomp.php, only the first element will be returned to the AJAX call. Assemble the string of html elements, and then return the variable outside the while loop

Comment: Don't just say "it is not working".  _In what way_ is it not working?  What is the expected/desired result?  What is the actual/undesired result?  Are you getting any errors (check your JS console as well as server logs)?  If so, what are the exact errors?  Are you getting output that doesn't match what you expect?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: Do you have a php error log? comes in handy

Comment: Start by removing  `value=""` from `<select class="form-control levelbox" id="region" value="" name="region">` Also your code is vulrenable to sql injection attacks. Try using prepared statements

Comment: @quirimmo that is a false statement. PHP generates html as it normally would if requested directly. Ajax will use the full output of PHP when the PHP script *ends*. So looping and echoing INSIDE the loop is perfectly valid html generation for an ajax call.

Comment: Check out your line in getcomp.php,  `echo '<option value="'.$row['region_id'].'">'.$row['comp_entered'].'</option>';`
I suspect the value should be $row['id'] and not $row['region_id']. If there are multiple options in the second dropbox, it appears they won't display unique values currently.

Comment: Your query won't work here `mysqli_query("select`. And I rather *you* see for yourself in the manual as to why that is. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php - I'm surprised nobody noticed that or bothered to tell you.

Comment: You're also leaving yourself open to a serious SQL injection. Use a prepared statement or add `(int)` to your POST array.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner You mean you don't usually just send your queries off into the vast nothingness and hope something answers?  :)

Comment: @PatrickQ *heh!* well, it *could* run, just not "work/execute" :-)

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm hesitant to post an answer for this, as it may open up a can of worms that I rather not have to deal with. I'm not a JS guy, so I couldn't help in that area.

Comment: I'd love to help, but not until OP responds to my original request.  As it stands, this is looking like yet another drive-by.

Comment: ...........yepper.

Comment: Hi everyone thanks for all the responses! Sorry I am not able to respond much quicker as I am a stay at home mom of a toddler and a baby while trying to learn php. XD
@ patrick Q sorry you are right, I should have been more detailed about the error I was getting. I posted this question quickly in the morning, but I will definitely be able to update my question later tonight when the kids are sleeping. Thanks everyone for taking the time to look at my question!

Comment: @Jordan Thank you!  I will be sure to check error logs first next time!

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue! Thanks to Jordan who pointed out that I should check my error log!! The issue was in my getcomp.php file.

I am posting the answer here in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Here is the correct code:

```
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sql= "select * from comp_entered where region_id='$id'";
$res= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['region_id'].'">'.$row['comp_entered'].'</option>';
}
}
?>
```

Thank you again to Jordan

Comment: Cheers! Glad you were able to find your answer. I would also look into prepared statements for better security :)

Comment: Yes you are right. I built this entire site on mysqli and I am not looking forward to learning and switching to PDO. Is there not a way to prevent sql injection with mysqli?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I switched all of my `mysqli` statements for object oriented. ex: `$run = $con->prepare($sql);` then `$run->bind_param("i",$var);` and then `$run->execute();` I found this to be a lot more understandable than procedural. Personally, I have not used PDO so I cannot speak on it but I'm sure these are both great ways to get the job done

Comment: Thanks! Iwill try object oriented